# Call content script of Chrome Extension from webpage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want the current web page to be able to call a function in the content script  of a Chrome Extension (if it detects the function's existence) to get a value back.

The whole flow would be this:

1. A user clicks a button on the web page.
2. A web page function calls the extension content script function.
3. The function in the extension content script sends a message to the background script.
4. The background script sends a native message to a native messaging host.
5. The host responds with a value to the background script.
6. The background script sends the value to the active tab (content script again).
7. The active tab somehow makes the value available to the web page function (not sure how this would work. Maybe the webpage adds a callback function to a queue and passes the queue id round-trip so the active tab knows which callback to call?)

I'm not sure how to do step 2. Is this possible?

Comment: @Teepeemm, The web page is being developed by another group. So I can request that things be added, but it's not guaranteed. You can safely assume that the button will already exist on the page and it's click handler will be looking for my function to call if it exists.

Comment: @Teepeemm, I'm assuming I'll have to add a script block to the page in order to make the function available to them, but I don't know how to get it to communicate with the content script.

Comment: @Teepeemm, sure, as long as the web page has access to the click handler, that'd be fine too.

Comment: You can send a message and get a reponse directly from the webpage to your background script. See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage

Comment: @rsanchez, thanks. Looks like exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @rsanchez, you should add that as an answer.